# Sending message via facebook-sdk (Python)

Tags: python, facebook

I've searched around for awhile hoping to find some answers, but I haven't found anything. I was wondering if anyone had a problem where xmpp actually connected but for some reason the message wasn't sent. When I run my code, the terminal will output "sent" implying that my message is sent. However when I ask the recipient, it appears they've never received a message. Here's a code snippet of my function. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
def send_msg(item_count, messages):
# Sender #
jid = '...@chat.facebook.com'

# Recipient #
to = '-...@chat.facebook.com'

xmpp = SendMsgBot(jid,to, unicode(messages))

xmpp.credentials['api_key'] = app_id
xmpp.credentials['access_token'] = fb_token

if xmpp.connect(('chat.facebook.com', 5222)):
    xmpp.process(block=True)
    print 'sent'
else:
    print 'message failed'
```

Comment: The Chat API is deprecated in API v2.0. So even if you are using API v1.0 it will stop working at 4/30/2015. Just so you don't put in a bunch of time to see it not working later.

Comment: Probably want to check if you have `xmpp_login` permission.

Comment: How could I go about acquiring a xmpp_login permission @phwd?I checked the explorer tools page and when I was selecting permissions off of the box I didn't see xmpp_login in the extended permissions...

Comment: It's probably because you are using a v2.0 app as WizKid already explained.